# Why do I have an indentation error in this Python code

Tags: python, tkinter

Am I just crazy here?  This was running the other day and now when I try to run it, I get the following error.  Is it possible there is some other problem with the code and that's why it's not running or is it specifically saying that I have indented line 10 incorrectly?  I'm kind of lost on this.

```
python phonebookapp.py
  File "phonebookapp.py", line 10
    self.text.pack()
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

?

```
from Tkinter import *
import sqlite3

class Hello():
    def __init__(self, master):

        frame=Frame(master, width=80, height=50)
        frame.pack()

        self.text = Label(frame, text="         ")
        self.text.pack()
        self.text.grid(row=0, sticky=W)

        self.lab = Label(frame, text="name")
        self.lab.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.lab.grid(row=1)

        self.TextField = Entry(frame, text = "name", width=30)
        self.TextField.insert(0, "Enter Name")
        self.TextField.pack()
        self.TextField.grid(row=1)
        self.TextField.bind("Button-1", clearEvent)

        self.TextField2 = Entry(frame, text = "age", width=30)
        self.TextField2.insert(0, "Enter Age")
        self.TextField2.pack()
        self.TextField2.grid(row=2)

        self.TextField3 = Entry(frame, text = "phone", width=30)
        self.TextField3.insert(0, "Enter Phone #")
        self.TextField3.pack()
        self.TextField3.grid(row=3)

        self.TextField4 = Entry(frame, text = "fblink", width=30)
        self.TextField4.insert(0, "Enter Facebook Link")
        self.TextField4.pack()
        self.TextField4.grid(row=4)

        self.btn=Button(frame, text='Add', command=self.add_note)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="w")

        self.showbtn = Button(frame, text='Update', command=self.show_notes)
        self.showbtn.pack()
        self.showbtn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="")

        self.delbtn = Button(frame, text='Delete', command=self.del_notes)
        self.delbtn.pack()
        self.delbtn.grid(row=5, rowspan=1, sticky="e")


        self.content=Listbox(master, width=50)
        self.content.pack()

    def clearEvent(self, event):
        self.TextField.delete(0,END)


    def add_note(self):
        if self.TextField.get() == "":
            self.text["text"] = "Please type sumting"
        else:
            item = self.TextField.get()
            item2 = self.TextField2.get()
            item3 = self.TextField3.get()
            item4 = self.TextField4.get()

            conn = sqlite3.connect('phonebook1.db')
            c = conn.cursor()
            conn.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people(name TEXT primary key,
                       age TEXT, phone TEXT, fblink TEXT)''')
            c.execute("insert into people values (?, ?, ?, ?)", (item, item2, item3, item4))
            conn.commit()
            list=c.execute("SELECT * FROM people")
            conn.commit()

            for row in list:
                self.content.insert(END, row)
            c.close()
            self.TextField.delete(0, END)
            self.TextField2.delete(0, END)
            self.TextField3.delete(0, END)
            self.TextField4.delete(0, END)

    def show_notes(self):
        conn = sqlite3.connect('phonebook1.db')

        c =conn.cursor()
        listbox.delete(0, END)
        list=c.execute("SELECT * FROM people")
        conn.commit()

        for row in list:
            self.content.insert(END, row)
        c.close()

    def del_notes(self):
        pass

root=Tk()
application = Hello(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The line above that line starts with four spaces and a tab.

That line starts with two tabs.

To Python, a tab is a different (larger) indent than four spaces, even if they happen to look the same in your text editor (and on StackOverflow*).

This is why you should never, ever, ever mix tabs and spaces. Ideally, always use spaces, never tabs; if you insist on using tabs, then never use spaces. Use an editor that makes that hard to do or detects it for you, and run your code with the `-tt` flag.

---

* The extra four spaces uses to indent a code block plus four spaces at the start of a line of code will look exactly like four spaces plus a tab, because that tab jumps to the tabstop at the eighth space, so it ends up looking valid in SO, even though it isn't. That probably isn't the same reason it looks valid in your text editor; it's just a coincidence that they both turn out the same in this very common case. At any rate, that means the only way to find tab problems on SO is to look at the question source and move the cursor around and see if it jumps over multiple spaces with a single left arrow.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are mixing spaces and tabs. On the line before you have spaces and one tab and on the other lines you have 2 tabs.

I'd recommend you to use 4 spaces instead of 1 tab, everywhere, as suggested in [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).